# How do I remove duplicate rows on returned related data in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a query that joins many related tables together and as a result, it returns duplicate rows for those items with multiple data against them.

I've searched for answers to this on stack and via google but all the results show things like using 'DISTINCT' or creating a subquery.  I can't get any solution to work and I think the confusion I face is because of the many joins I have.

Can someone guide me on how to stop my results shows duplicates?  Here is my query so far.

```
SELECT dbo.Vessel.VesselId, 
       dbo.Vessel.Name, 
       dbo.Capacity.DeckAreaM2, 
       dbo.Vessel.DPClassId, 
       dbo.Subsea.Accomodation, 
       dbo.Subsea.RovHangar, 
       dbo.Crane.SWL
FROM   dbo.Vessel INNER JOIN
       dbo.Capacity ON dbo.Vessel.VesselId = dbo.Capacity.VesselId LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.DeckEquipment ON dbo.Vessel.VesselId = dbo.DeckEquipment.VesselId LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.Crane ON dbo.DeckEquipment.DeckEquipmentId = dbo.Crane.DeckEquipmentId LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.Subsea ON dbo.Vessel.VesselId = dbo.Subsea.VesselId
```

Comment: Impossible to help you.   Give us an example of duplicate rows that are not being removed by DISTINCT and the other methods you tried.

Comment: Left inner join??? Also, you should learn how to use aliases. 3 part naming in the column list has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, does your query even work? There's no such thing as `LEFT INNER JOIN` ; you may have an `INNER JOIN`, a `LEFT JOIN`, or a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, with the latter two being the same.

Second, I can understand your non-willingness to make an additional subquery, but why are you against the `DISTINCT` operator?

Third, if you use a `GROUP BY` and put there *ONLY* the fields you want, it will be equivelant to a `DISTINCT` operator and will return the results you need.

Last but not least, you need to show us what you are getting and what you want instead, if we are to be able to help you more.